GPG error OBS Studio - How to fix this?
GPG error OBS Studio - How to fix this?



Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

When you take your question to a site that supports your chosen Linux Mint, I suggest include text (rather than a picture of text), as that will allow copy/pasting of your error message into a specific answer related to that PPA & your chosen OS/release...
